# Best way to detect specific image in realtime, Android (JAVA)

Tags: java, android

I want to make an application that will detect one specific image (I made a logo for my website that I want to print out and detect) in Android. I spent the last day researching but almost all results include python and I'd like to make it with Java.

To explain my idea furthermore, I'd like to do this in real time. So basicly you would open the app and then you would hover camera over image (my logo) and the phone would play you a sound that is already in the application. I understand it would be better to connect with the database, but I'd like to make this an offline application.

Anything you can provide from tutorials to documentation to already written programs to modify, best tools to use for doing this, basicly any information will be very helpful. Thanks!

Comment: You may want to look into OpenCV

Comment: @varunkr tnx, I will. I did not know it supports Android.